# Disabling cut,copy options in Window7

Tags: windows

I need to disable cut ,copy options in the right click menu of windows7.
They should be displayed in menu,But when i click any of them they should not perform their respected operations.

What could be possible way to do so?Is their any software to do it?If yes,Please provide a link for it.

Comment: Have you seen http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/disable-copy-or-cut-and-paste-completely/125d5548-3c33-4157-9dfe-8933b85cc031?auth=1 ?

Comment: @manlio Yeah,But it doent provide any suitable answer to do so.So please help